# Can't login with any account - No error message shown

Tags: login, wp-login-form

I'm trying to login to one of my Wordpress sites through the /wp-login.php link. When submitting the login form the page refreshes but does not re-direct to the /wp-admin.php dashboard.

I've tried typing an incorrect password (to check if the login details are wrong) and I do get an "incorrect password" message as expected, however when I type the correct details no error messages are displayed.

I've attempted to reset the password through the "Forgot password" page, but I get the following error message:

```
"Could not save password reset key to database."
```

The site is hosted through AWS's Elastic Beanstalk with an Amazon Aurora instance powering the DB. When attempting to reset the password through MySQL I am hit with a "Read Only" error.

All posts are being loaded from the DB correctly, so I know it's not an issue with the DB presenting data in response to a query.

I've cleared all cache and cookies for this in the hope that it was just a cache/cookie conflict however I'm still not able to login through any user account on the WP install.

The site was working fine a few days ago and nothing has been changed since then - No new posts, no updates etc.

Has anyone experienced this before and how can I fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure it's related to WordPress itself, maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665588/aws-aurora-the-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-read-only-option-so-it-cannot

Answer (score 0):

These issues all point to data not being saved to the database - As prompted by Stefano Tombolini's comment on the question, I changed the database connection host.

The cause of this issue is that I had originally connected to an instance inside of a database cluster rather than the cluster itself. Occasionally the instances in the cluster change role between reader and writer. This caused the instance that I was connecting to to be read-only.

See this post about solving this issue:
[stackoverflow.com/questions/46665588/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665588/aws-aurora-the-mysql-server-is-running-with-the-read-only-option-so-it-cannot)